# Jquery tabs initial tab selection

Tags: jquery-ui

I've implemented jquery tabs and want to call the page they are on in two ways.  Firstly with the first tab open and the others hidden which works fine.  But secondly I want tab 4 to be visible when landing on the page.  So I have simply duplicated the page - Page A opens with the first tab in view.  Page B has this code....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() { 
      $("#tabs").tabs( 'select' , 3 ) 
    }); 
</script>
```

and opens the forth tab.  BUT it opens the first tab first then flashes to tab 4.

How can I get the page to open tab 4 initially without opening the first tab first.
Hope you can follow my ramble!!!

Nick

Answer (score 0):

That would be how to open to the 4th tab using their API.

Perhaps you can try hiding the tab div, creating it, and then showing it in the `show` event when the 4th tab is shown (which will happen after everything is initialized).

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be an obvious solution.  One suggestion I have seen is to use jQuery to keep the tabs hidden until they have loaded and then show them after the selection has taken place.